# Loading... message on jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How can I make the [jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete) show "Loading..." in the dropdown while it's loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin adds a class "ac_loading" to the input while its loading.
The default stylesheet defines a background image (indicator.gif) for
that class.

You can put here your text or image dynamic...

**Edit:**  MM I see you using the jQueryUI autocomplete. But I think you can do it the same way. Just put text in the class the autocomplete plugin creates after you define your object as autocomplete

Comment: How could I set the text in it instead of using indicator.gif?  Is there a way to do that through css?

Comment: mm you can't put thext into a element with css... you should do that with jquery, or doing it the simple way and add a picture with the text loading... 
But I see you can't dynamic add text with jQuery to the ac_loading class because the plugin creates the 'ac_results' div only when you give the plugin a hint by though a key-event

Comment: michel, how (and where) should I add text w/ jquery to the class?